# Ask question in different way

Tags: meaning

For example When ask İf use of any preposition like with is correct or not  i say “ would it be correct to use with in sentence “. Can i say instead of this sentence:

> Would “with” be correct to use in sentence ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could say either of these, with the same meaning.

1. Would it be correct to use the word "with" in this sentence?
2. Would the word “with” be correct in this sentence?

There's no error in this third choice, but it it does not sound natural to me. There seems to be no reason to include the words "to use."

3. Would the word "with" be correct to use in this sentence?